# SherlockActionBar up button won't work on API 10

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I'm playing around with the sherlockactionbar library, there is a problem which is the up button won't work on API 10. The up icon can be shown on the actionbar, but it won't respond to my pressing. On higher API such as 16, it functions as expected without problems.
I tried several solutions I came across, but none of them work. Below is one of them.

```
switch (item.getItemId()) {
  case android.R.id.home:

     NavUtils.navigateUpTo(this, new Intent(this, test.class));
     return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have these set:

```
getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

And that your switch is in this method:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        /* Do Something //*/
        return true;
    default:
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, it is my settings screen which extends SherlockPreferenceActivity. I found out just now that when in 4.x.x devices, all you have to do is add "getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);", the up button will work, DON'T include "onOptionsItemSelected" to watch the android.R.id.home or else it won't work again. But on the contrary, on lower API device such as my 2.3.6, you have to include "getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)" and "NavUtils.navigateUpTo(this, new Intent(this, test.class));" in "onOptionsItemSelected", in order to go to its parent.

Comment: @TonyTong if that is the case, then I think your best bet would be to call "super.onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem)" before going through the switch instead of as the default. That way it would work for both earlier versions as well. I'm assuming that ActionBarSherlock overrides the onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem) itself, so we should call the superclass. I'll edit my answer.